# Using temporary data in SQL query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table (`maintable`) of the format:

```
(id, intcol1, intcol2, intcol3, ...)
```

Sample data:

```
123, 582585, 25215718, 15519
234, 2583, 2371, 1841948
345, 42389, 234289, 234242
```

I want to run some aggregate calculations using outside data to group the data by. The data I have is of the form:

```
(id, groupcol)
```

Sample data:

```
123, "January",
234, "February"
345, "January"
```

In this case, suppose I want the SUM of `intcol1` using the provided groupings to match IDs, the result would be:

```
"January", 624974               # 42389 + 582585
"February", 2583
```

My question is: How do I get the "group data" into the query? Using a `WITH` clause and JOINING it against the `maintable`? Or adding it to a temporary table and using that in a following query?

I can manipulate the data I have and format it however way is easiest from the program running the SQL query.

What is the best / fastest / simplest method?

*Edited for clarity*

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Done!

Comment: Where does the `624974 ` in `624974 + 582585` come from?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Me working too fast >_< Fixed now

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a simple join and group by:

```
select t2.groupcol, 
       sum(t1.intcol1)
from maintable t1 
  join table_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t2.groupcol;
```

If you don't have that "outside" data in a table, you can do something like this:

```
select t2.groupcol, 
       sum(t1.intcol1)
from maintable t1 
  join (
    values 
      (123, 'January'), 
      (234, 'February'),
      (345, 'January')
  ) as t2 (id, groupcol) on t1.id = t2.id
group by t2.groupcol;
```